# Is there a PowerShell function to reconnect to a SQL Server after restart?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I have a basic Microsoft SQL Server (SQL Server 2017 on Server 2016 Datacenter) in Azure that's currently being power-managed. Every morning I RDP into the VM, enter the SQL Server Management Studio, and reconnect using my local admin account.

The machines automatically reboot, but is there a way to automate the reconnection process?

I reconnect using a GUI interface with the fields:

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: hostname
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
  User name: localadmin
  Password:

I then click connect and boom. It seems like there should be a function, something like:

```
Reconnect-SQLServer -Type DatabaseEngine -Name hostname 
         -Authentication Windows -Credentials $Credentials
```

Is there? I haven't been able to find one. Bear with me, I'm fairly new to this sort of stuff.

Edit: It was my impatience. After a short period of time, the database was online and automatically reconnected. The manual process was not needed. Thanks to those who tried to help out.

Comment: What do you mean by "reconnect"? Reconnect **what** to **what**, exactly?

Comment: The Server, "hostname", is the Site database for a Citrix deployment. The Broker will query "hostname" for user authorized resources. Users cannot connect to any sessions without this "reconnection." It is SQL Server 2017 @Dai

Comment: So you just need to open an arbitrary TDS connection to the SQL Server instance using your own Windows User account and some Citrix backend magic acts on that?

Comment: In Citrix eyes' the SQL server does not exist until it is connected. @Dai

Comment: _The machines automatically reboot, but is there a way to automate the reconnection process?_ I don't quie understand, but you could use `SQLCMD` to connect to it. But it into a batch file (or powershell or whatever) and run it on startup https://serverfault.com/questions/85323/run-bat-file-at-startup

Answer (score 0):

You can automate connecting sql server management studio  with `SSMS.exe` flags like:

```sh
# use current running credentials for windows authentication
SSMS.exe -E -S hostname -d MyDatabase -nosplash

# use specific user account (will prompt for password)
SSMS.exe -U MyUserName -S hostname -d MyDatabase
```

It kind of sounds like you need something to just end the power-management? It would depend on how that is configured

---

I'm not familiar with Citrix, but it looks like there is a powershell module for monitoring/managing it and its database connections with cmdlets like `Get-BrokerServerStatus` for example:

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX232979/how-to-connect-site-to-sql-ha-sql-mirror-or-a-new-sql-server-after-migrating-your-database